# phpMyAdmin streams.php allocate a lot of memory

Tags: phpmyadmin

File streams.php wants to allocate a lot of memory. I have the latest version of phpMyAdmin.

> Error message: Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 205520896 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 3087007745 bytes) in /phpMyAdmin/libraries/php-gettext/streams.php on line 113.

Comment: What are you trying to do when this error occurs? Does it occur immediately after logging in?

Comment: Error occurs when I run phpMyAdmin panel before logging on. After comment 159-165 lines in file gettext.php error disappeared, but it is not a solution

Comment: What web server are you using and what PHP version? In your phpMyAdmin configuration (`config.inc.php`) what is the auth_type -- config, cookie, or http?

Comment: I use Apache and PHP Version 5.3.29. auth_type is set to cookie, but change to http did not help.